# New font doesn't size as it should

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

So I finally got the Birch font installed on my WordPress site. Now the font isn't sizing as I would expect it to be ([click here](http://www.shanaraeshairdesign.com/concept/)). I have tried editing `font-size, line-height, font-weight, font-style, ...` Nothing seems to work. Strange thing is, on iPhone it works like a charm.

In my header I have added this.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen, print">
@font-face {
font-family: Birch;
    src: url('../wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../wp-content/themes/zenon-lite/fonts/birch.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body { font-family: Birch, Tahoma; }
p {font-size: 1.5em;}
</style>
```

Comment: Where is the `font-size` declared above?

Comment: I test it in `Inspect Element` as that's faster. Added `font-size: 100%`

Comment: It reads `100%` of the inherited element, but you have nowhere font declared, so it shall take `body` default font size.

Comment: @NathanLee, added it to the Font-Face declaration, this makes it even smaller. Or am I wrong again?

Comment: You need to set font-size for the body and then proportionately add sizes for other tags or make them fixed with pixels by adding them individually.

Comment: Ok, edited my post again. Size is bigger, but still is bold and the letters are too near. `Font-weight` doesn't seem to do much difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39912/discussion-between-nathan-lee-and-t-thielemans)

Comment: Thanks once again @NathanLee! :)

Answer (score 1):

You've set the font-size on the `body` but nowhere else. Therefore your typographical elements are being rendered at the browser default size. You need to define the sizes on the individual components too, for example:

CSS:

```
h1 {
 font-size: 2em;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Size has increased, but still bold and very narrow. Any suggestion on that?

Comment: Birch is a narrow font by default - http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/Birch/

Comment: With this typeface I believe so. The other alternative would be to use a CSS transform to scale the text horizontally, although this will probably break your layout p{transform: scale(1.5, 1);}. I would suggest keeping Birch for headings where it is more legible at larger sizes, and chose a wider typeface for the body text